# In Sketchup, is it possible to automate dwg 2D line exports of scenes as you can with view.write_image?

Tags: batch-file, export, scene, sketchup, dwg

I would like to have a one click solution for exporting my Sketchup Pro 8 Scenes to individual 2D dwg files, similar to that using view.write_image?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the SketchUp Ruby API doesn't expose any means of exporting 2D DWGs. You can only export 3D.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use [sketchup-dxf-stl-exporter](https://github.com/NB70/sketchup-dxf-stl-exporter) to control your export in .dxf format. For example you can move all you 2D entities to a special layer

```
autocad_entities = Array.new

Sketchup.active_model.entities.each do |entitie|
    autocad_entities.push entitie if entitie.layer.name == 'AutoCad Layer'
end
```

and use **skp_to_dxf.rb** to export these entities.

Hope it help you.